# ESP32 Classic Bluetooth Set Password

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, esp32

I am using ESP32 classic Bluetooth Feature for data transfer. I am using the SerialToSerialBT example. I am able to scan and discover the Bluetooth device from my smartphone. But the pairing is without any security/passcode. It simply pairs immediately. How to make the pairing using PIN/Passkey entry?

**Hardware**: ESP32 DEV Kit V1

**Software** Arduino IDE

**Code:**

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("Starting..");
  SerialBT.begin("MyESP32"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
  
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: the BluetoothSerial header files has `bool setPin(const char *pin);` (PIN as personal identification number)